# SnapKit 3.0.0 Swift3 error

Tags: swift3, snapkit

I get error. when install "SnapKit 3.0.0"

> Argument labels '(offset:)' do not match any available overloads
>
> Argument labels '(inset:)' do not match any available overloads
>
> Argument labels '(priority:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: This lib is not really ready for Swift 3 yet, they say you have to fix the deprecated syntax yourself: https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit/blob/master/Documentation/SnapKit%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md The way to do that is to inspect the source, I guess, and/or let Xcode's autocomplete guide you.